# How often are sitemap.xml checked for updates by crawlers?

Tags: web-crawlers, xml-sitemap

How often do crawlers check for updates in submitted `sitemap.xml`? Every hour, day, week, month, more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's depends on which search engine you refer to. Most people are interested in google so I'll assume that's what you meant:
Generally speaking, the higher your rank is, and if the frequency in which you change your site (add articles etc) is high - your site will be crawled [more frequently](http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/022057.html).

The [following article](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/10-ways-to-increase-your-site-crawl-rate/7159/) might interest you.

Answer (score 5):

Let's try an empirical approach.

In the access logs for [my site](http://lup.vyznev.net), I see 55 sitemap requests over the last 33 days.  Out of those 55, 30 are from [Googlebot](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/hh204496.aspx), 21 from [msnbot](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/hh204496.aspx) and the remaining four are from [Exabot](http://www.exabot.com/go/robot).  (I've only submitted the sitemap manually to Google; the others have [found it through robots.txt](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_robots).)

So that's one data point for about "every day", at least for Google and for a smallish site like mine.  Although I should note that I regenerate the sitemap daily, so it's possible that Googlebot is simply observing a pattern in the last modification timestamps and adapting to it.

If you want to directly inform search engines that your sitemap has been updated, you can do so by [sending an HTTP ping](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_ping).  This *may* make the search engines reload your sitemap sooner, although of course there are no guarantees.